# Symfony4 setter where getter match id route?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm kindly new on Symfony

I'm doing a vote system but i guess this should work for like,

At the moment my controller function is this, this only create a new row with 1vote, but not update any $id created before.

```
/**
     * @Route("/public/{id}/vote", name="poll_vote", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function vote(Request $request, Poll $poll): Response
    {
       $inc = 1;
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $entity = new Poll();
       $entity->setVotes($inc++);
       $em->persist($entity);
       $em->flush();
       }
       return $this->redirectToRoute('poll_public');
    }
```

This is my button from twig template

```
<a href="{{ path('poll_vote', {'id': poll.id}) }}">
```

An this is my entity

```
  class Poll
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $votes;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVotes(): ?int
    {
        return $this->votes;
    }

    public function setVotes(?int $votes): self
    {
        $this->votes = $votes;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have no idea about how can match my getID from my entity and match for the $id from the @Route.

Any guide or suggestion would be really appreciate.

Thanks

EDIT:

Updated with the correct function after Arne answer:

```
/**
     * @Route("/public/{id}", name="poll_vote", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function vote($id)
    {
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $poll = $entityManager->getRepository(Poll::class)->find($id);

    if (!$poll) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No polls found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    $poll->setVotes($poll->getVotes()+1);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('poll_public', [
        'id' => $poll->getId()
    ]);
    }
```

Comment: `$request->query->get('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you have to get the ID from your request, query the Entitty Repository for your Poll Entity, update the votes and persist it back to your database.

1. Get the ID from your request

   $id = $request->query->get('id');
2. Query the repository:

   $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $poll= $entityManager->getRepository(Poll::class)->find($id);
3. Update the votes:

   $poll->setVotes($poll->getVotes()+1);
4. Persist to the DB:

   $entityManager->persist($poll);

   $entityManager->flush();

Alternatively you could also use the [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#automatically-fetching-objects-paramconverter) to let Symfony get the Poll object for you. More information about updating objects can be found in the [Doctrine Guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object).

Note that yor route will only match existing polls, since id is a required parameter in the URL. You might add another route  without an ID which is being used for creating new Poll entities.

Comment: Thanks Arne, that is just what i looking for, now is working as i expected. thanks!.